# 500 Internal Server Error when calling ajax in spring

Tags: java, ajax, spring, spring-mvc

I am using Spring MVC and I have an AJAX which is used to delete selected user. It's working fine on my local system but when I tried to run the same code on development server I'm getting

> 500 Internal Server Error

I did google to figure out what is wrong with my code but I'm not able to figure out anything till now. Any help will be appreciated.

AJAX function in my JSP file:

```
$('.del-btn .userId').click(function(){
    var userId = $(this).attr("alt");
    var data = 'userId='+ userId;
    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: '${pageContext.servletContext.contextPath}/deleteUser',
        data: data,
        success: function(response) {
            $('#submitkpi').submit();
        }
    });
});
```

`deleteUser` function in Controller:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/deleteUser", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public @ResponseBody Map<String, ? extends Object> deleteKpi(@ModelAttribute(value = "userId") String userId, BindingResult result) {

    if (!userId.isEmpty()) {
        userService.deleteUser(userId);
        return Collections.singletonMap("ok", true);
    }
    return Collections.singletonMap("errorMsg", "Unable to complete your request!");
}
```

Comment: Look in your server logfile and you will find out where the error is.

Comment: What is error you are getting.

Comment: @SumitGupta When I run this code on server side then I'm getting 500 Internal Server error but when I run the same code on my local It's working fine

Comment: yes, but what is the exception throwed by the server? can you post the server log? Or the error showed by the webbrowser?

Comment: @Luffy: You can try using `@RequestParam` instead of  `@ModelAttribute `

Comment: @Jens@David Herrero There is no logs created for this issue

Comment: have you checked that `userId` is not null?

Comment: @NayanjyotiDeka `@RequestParam` Worked fine foe me Thanks :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you try this?!

```
$('.del-btn .userId').click(function(){
    var userId = $(this).attr("alt");

    $.ajax({
        url: 'deleteUser',
        data: ({
                userId : userId,
            }),
        success: function(response) {
            alert(response)
        }
    });
});
```

Controller

```
@RequestMapping("/deleteUser")
@ResponseBody
public String deleteKpi(@RequestParam(value = "userId") Long userId,  HttpSession session) {

    if (null != userId) {
        userService.deleteUser(userId);
        return "Ok";
    }
    return "NotOk";
}
```